# Wordpress editor / subscriber role

Tags: wordpress, editor, subscriber

On one of my websites, the editor and subscriber have access to Dashboard, Profile and Plugins. This is really strange. There is no access to anything else - pages, posts etc.

Have tried re-installing wordpress and makes no difference.

Not using any user access plugins

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Chris

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid this is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Check out Wordpress' community forums http://wordpress.org/support/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should test the capabilities of your users and re structure them accordingly. Have a look at [The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) to get a list of capabilities for [editors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Editor) and [subscribers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Subscriber).

If you want to use plugins, you can find some that will allow you to edit the capabilities.

else you can then use [get_role()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_role), [add_cap()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) and [remove_cap()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap) to correct their capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to a standard theme such as twenty twelve and see if it woks properly, of it does the problem is your theme and you should contact the theme author.

Comment: Hi, it's not the theme. I think this plugin which was installed a while a go has broken it User Role Editor WordPress plugin http://shinephp.com/user-role-editor-wordpress-plugin/ 

Is there any way to re-insall capabilities in the database?

Comment: The usual advice on the WordPress forum is to switch to a standard theme and disable all plugins,  then reenable them until the problem returns. Removing the plugin should return things to normal, I don't expect it has modified the capabilities in the database.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. Managed to re-install the old plugin, remove restrictions and remove plugin.

Comment: You're welcome, you should up vote any helpful answers, especially the one you marked as correct.  You will also gain a badge by reading the whole FAQ.